# Google Adsense revenue slowing

Tags: adsense

I don't know where to ask this, so I'm going to just ask it here and handle the backlash when ever it comes.

First let me state that I'm familiar with the recent issues relating to ***Pepsi*** and ***YouTube*** how ever what I am currently unsure of is, *does this effect website publishers also*, or has my traffic just all around stopped converting?

I'm currently getting around 300,000 impressions per day and my revenue has dropped to as low as 0.19cpc when before it was sitting almost around a dollar for every registered click.

Question basically comes down to, are you guys getting effected by this also? What can I do in the mean time if this is in correlation with the advertisers opting out, because it's getting really hard to manage servers with no revenue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems to have had a drastic impact on my earnings as well, although I'm not doing anywhere close to the impressions you're doing.

My cpc and rpm have hit an all time low and its disastrous. I'm seeing the same cpc as you btw, we're not alone other publishers are complaining about the same issue.

I'm considering dropping a few adsense units till i see some better figures.

Comment: but usally 3 ad units in single page is allowed then why drop?